# Certain approximation in the setting of three expectation values does not make sense to me

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, approximation

I'm currently going through some lecture notes in the field of Bayes optimization and I'm currently looking at a expression looking like this:

$$\mathbb{E}_{x^*} \left[\mathbb{E}_y\left[\left\{\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*,y,x)\right]\right\}^n\right]\right]$$

Where in this problem $n$ is a very small number since we later want to let $n\to0$.

As a next step there is now an approximation introduced which looks like this:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X^n\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{n\log(X)}\right] \approx 1 + n\mathbb{E}\left[\log(X)\right] = e^{\log\left(1 + n\mathbb{E}\left[\log(X)\right]\right)} \approx e^{n\mathbb{E}\left[\log(X)\right]}.$$
The notes say that after applying this approximation, the original equation becomes
$$e^{n\mathbb{E}_{x*}\left[\mathbb{E}_y\left[\log\left(\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*,y,x)\right]\right)\right]\right]}$$
Which just doesn't make sense to me.

If I directly compare this term to the general form of $e^{n\mathbb{E}\left[\log(X)\right]}$, I must assume that our "$X$" in this case was $X=\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*, y, x)\right]$. But this makes me wonder how the expectation over $x^*$, namely $\mathbb{E}_{x^*}\left[\cdot\right]$, also got up into the exponent.

On the other hand, if the exponent $n$ was outside instead of inside the expectation over $y$, so that we would have something like $\mathbb{E}_{y}^{n}\left[\cdot\right]$, we could get the expectation over $x^*$ into the exponent but then the expectation over $y$ should also be inside the logarithm...

Either way I look at this, I don't really get how the result in the notes was obtained... I also wondered if the result is just false but I checked the numerical results of the final expression and it matches to widely known results.

If anyone might have a guess what could be going on here it would be really appreciated by me... Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, it is incorrect to state that
$$\mathbb{E}_{x^*} \left[\mathbb{E}_y\left[\left\{\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*,y,x)\right]\right\}^n\right]\right]=
e^{n\mathbb{E}_{x*}\left[\mathbb{E}_y\left[\log\left(\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*,y,x)\right]\right)\right]\right]}
$$
since
$$\mathbb{E}_{x^*} \left[\mathbb{E}_y\left[\left\{\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*,y,x)\right]\right\}^n\right]\right]=
\mathbb{E}_{x*}\left[\mathbb{E}_y\left[e^{n\log\left(\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*,y,x)\right]\right)}\right]\right]
$$
Given that the exponential function is increasing exponentially fast, the approximation only stands when $n\log\left(\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*,y,x)\right]\right)$ is both small and hardly varying in $x^*$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! So if, as you mentioned, $n\log(\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*,y,x)\right])$ fulfills those two conditions, then I would be allowed to pull the expectation over $x^*$ and $y$ up in the exponent? For completeness, I realized I could have also given a bit more background to the variables and the function $f$ itself. The function in this problem was defined as $$f(x^*, y, x) = e^{x^2 - xx^*-iyx}$$ and $y$ is i.i.d from $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $x^*$ and $x$ are both i.i.d from a distribution $P_X(x)$.

Comment: I think I got it now... If you do the approximation first with $X=\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*, y, x)\right]$ you get $$\mathbb{E}_{x^*}\left[e^{n\mathbb{E}_{y}\left[\log(\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*, y, x)\right])\right]}\right].$$ Applying the approximation a second time, but this time with $X = e^{\mathbb{E}_{y}\left[\log(\mathbb{E}_{x}\left[f(x^*, y, x)\right])\right]}$, leaves me with the result from the notes...